# Uploaded all of my files to public_html; still shows an "under construction" page

Tags: wordpress, hosting, web-hosting

I am having an issue setting up a new site for a friend of mine. I have completed building a WordPress site for my friend and I uploaded the new website to the public_html folder on the File Manager on the JustHost cPanel, but even with all of the contents on there it still shows a Network Solutions "Under Construction" page when I go to the web address.

I have tried taking all of the files out of the public_html folder and adding my own index.html to see if anything would show up and it does not. Everything I have tried does nothing but show an "Under Construction" page and I am not sure what the issue is. I have tried dozens of Google searches but nothing turns up any results or gives me any idea for a solution. Do you guys have an answer?

I'd appreciate any help that I could get. If you need me to clarify any information then please feel free to ask.

Thank you very much!

Comment: check that there isnt a .htaccess file overriding the paths - I would suggest that this is a Customer Service call to JustHost

Comment: was there anything else in the public_html prior to your upload? i.e. that Construction Page? Delete it :)

Comment: What is the directory structure like on the server? And have you tried clearing your cache or another browser?

Comment: It sounds like the DNS is not pointed to your hosting. Send me the domain and I can verify it for you.

Answer (score 2):

Hope this solves your problem:

Head over to the CPanel. Under "Files" tab, click on File Manager.

Locate the folder "Public_html" and click it.

Under the folder, find "index.html" file.

You see it? If yes delete index.html file.

Done. Your site should be live now.

CAUTION: Don't delete any other thing apart from index.html file.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check in admin if your blog is checked to publish mode or under maintance mode?
Do you have a plugin installed call Wp-Maintence Mode or something?

Answer (score 0):

Go to your domain manager. Edit DNS and add an A record with @ as value and enter TTL as 1hr and point it to your server IP. Wait for 3-4 hours before your domain gets fully propagated.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps and you will be able to resolve the issue:

1. Go to CPanel and click on "File Manager". Under that, locate the folder `Public_html` (Where your Wordpress site is Located).
2. Now see whether you have `index.html` file stored in `Public_html` folder.
3. If yes, Delete `Index.html` file  because you only require `index.php` file for your site to run.
   Note: Never ever delete `index.php` file.